# Java 8 streams: Convert String[] to Float[]

Tags: java, type-conversion, java-stream

I have an array `String[]` and I'd like to convert to array `Float[]`

Consider `e` is a `String[]` supplied via `HttpServletRequest::getParameterMap()`. I tried:

```
Arrays.stream(e.getValue()).mapToDouble(Float::parseFloat).boxed().toArray(Float[]::new));
```

Got exception:

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Double

So then I tried:

```
Arrays.stream(e.getValue()).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).boxed().toArray(Float[]::new));
```

Same result.

Comment: Replace `mapToDouble` for a DoubleStream of doubles with `map` for String input parameters for parseFloat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream(e.getValue()).map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to generate a `Float[]` array:

```
Arrays.stream(e.getValue()).map(Float::valueOf).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

You have to handle possible `NumberFormatException`.

Unfortunately, there is no class `FloatStream` for primitive `float`, but since you want to get an `Float[]` anyway, the code above is just fine.

Comment: Duplicates [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565832/303810).

Comment: @Ivar Thanks I fixed that.

Comment: @lexicore Well, I added some more comments then the answer you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You are still generating a `Float[]` array in your second test.

For a `Double[]` result, use:

```
Arrays
    .stream(e.getValue())
    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
    .boxed()
    .toArray(Double[]::new);
```

For a `Float[]` result (no need for `boxed` in this case), use:

```
Arrays
    .stream(e.getValue())
    .map(Float::parseFloat)
    .toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Comment: The objective is to create `Float[]`, not `Double[]`.

Comment: @lexicore oops. Amending.